# Daily Notification comes random with Alarmanager

Tags: android, notifications

Currently I try to setup a Daily Notification in my app everything work, but the daily notifications doesn't work it comes randomly.

MainActivity how i set the Alarmanager:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationDbReceiver.class);
    Intent start = new Intent(this, StartService.class);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            if (calendar.before(now)) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
                    .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
            } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
            }
```

Thats my BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, StartService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}
```

And this is my Service:

```
public class StartService extends Service {

private final int ID = 0;

private Context mContext;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mContext = getBaseContext();

    Log.i("onCreate", "I'm in");

    createNotification();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void createNotification() {
    Log.i("createNotification", "I'm in");
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.primary))
            .setContentTitle("Blablabla")
            .setContentText("Blablabla")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Blablabla"))
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, mIntent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);
    Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
    mNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext).notify(ID, mNotification);
}  
}
```

I hope someone can help me. I have already read some Questions here on stackoverflow, but no answer from the Questions helped me.

Comment: With the code you've posted, I would expect the alarm to fire pretty much immediately after setting it. Is that what's happening?

Comment: it doesn't fire immediately, because i get a notification mostly in the time between 10 minutes or 30 minutes

Comment: Hmm, OK. Well, anyway, you're not setting the alarm's time correctly. Notice that you initialize a `Calendar` instance with the desired time, but you never pass that time in the `AlarmManager#set*()` calls. You pass `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY`, which is always in the past on the real-time clock. Instead, you want to pass `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: Ok, i need set instead of `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` the time from the Calendar `calendar.getTimeInMillis();` 

Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Comment: Ok thx @Mike M. I try it :-)

Comment: So it notificate me on 10 o'clock but 15min after i get a new notification why?

Comment: Not sure, but I would guess that your `Service` got killed and recreated, so the `Notification` was re-issued. You're not overriding the `onStartCommand()` method, and its default return value is `START_STICKY`. If all you're doing with this `Service` is issuing the `Notification`, you should use an `IntentService` instead, which will stop itself automatically. Otherwise, you can call `stopSelf()` in the `Service` you have now, after it's done with whatever it needs to do.

Comment: Thx for the help it's now work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are initializing the `AlarmManager` multiple times (for example, whenever the `Activity` starts). Try to set it only once and check.

Comment: I already check before I call the method, is the service running